# Chaining this query throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am trying to make a query that:

1. Finds/Gets the object (Coupon.code)
2. Checks if the coupon is expired (expires_at)
3. Checks if the coupon has been used up. (coupons_remaining)

I got some syntax using a newer version of ruby but it isnt working with my version 2.2.1 The syntax I have is

```
  def self.get(code)
   where(code: normalize_code(code)).
   where("coupon_count > ? OR coupon_count IS NULL", 0).
   where("expires_at > ? OR expires_at IS NULL", Time.now).
   take(1)
 end
```

This throws an error of `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` which is because my rails doesn't seem to recognize the 2 arguments ("coupon_count > ? OR coupon_count IS NULL", 0) so I have tried to change it but when I change them to something like this (which in my heart felt horribly wrong)

```
def self.get(code)
 where(code: normalize_code(code)).
 where(coupon_count: self.coupon_count > 0 || self.coupon_count.nil? ).
 where(expires_at: self.expires_at > Time.now || self.expires_at.nil? ).
 take(1)
end
```

I get `` undefined method `coupon_count' for Coupon:Class ``

I am short on ideas can someone help me get the syntax for this get method in my model? By the way if it matters I am using mongoid 5.1.0

Comment: You can't define a `where` like you do in the second case, those methods don't exist. That can be used to specify things like `coupon_count: N` where N is some value, but there's no way of converting a `.nil?` test to `IS NULL`, not in regular ActiveRecord anyway. If the first one is failing, which is the correct notation, it might be an issue with your version of Rails. Which one are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.0.10 and ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain. Combining OR and AND in MongoDB is a bit messy because you're not really working with a query language at all, you're just building a hash. Similar complications apply if you might apply multiple conditions to the same field. This is also why you can't include SQL-like snippets like you can with ActiveRecord.

For example, to express:

```
"coupon_count > ? OR coupon_count IS NULL", 0
```

you need to build a hash like:

```
:$or => [
    { :coupon_count.gt => 0   },
    { :coupon_count    => nil }
]
```

but if you try to add another OR to that, you'll overwrite the existing `:$or` key and get confusion. Instead, you need to be aware that there will be multiple ORs and manually avoid the duplicate by saying `:$and`:

```
:$and => [
    {
        :$or => [
            { :coupon_count.gt => 0   },
            { :coupon_count    => nil }
        ]
    }, {
        :$or => [
            { :expires_at.gt => Time.now },
            { :expires_at    => nil      }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then adding the `code` condition is straight forward:

```
:code => normalize_code(code),
:$and => [ ... ]
```

That makes the whole thing a rather hideous monstrosity:

```
def self.get(code)
  where(
    :code => normalize_code(code),
    :$and => [
      {
        :$or => [
          { :coupon_count.gt => 0   },
          { :coupon_count    => nil }
        ]
      }, {
        :$or => [
          { :expires_at.gt => Time.now },
          { :expires_at    => nil      }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ).first
end
```

You could also use `find_by(that_big_mess)` instead of `where(that_big_mess).first`. Also, if you expect the query to match multiple documents, then you probably want to add an `order` call to make sure you get the one you want. You could probably use the `and` and `or` query methods instead of a single hash but I doubt it will make things easy to read, understand, or maintain.

I try to avoid ORs with MongoDB because the queries lose their little minds fast and you're left with some gibbering eldritch horror that you don't want to think about too much. You're usually better off precomputing parts of your queries with generated fields (that you have to maintain and sanity check to make sure they are correct); for example, you could add another field that is true if `coupon_count` is positive or `nil` and then update that field in a `before_validation` hook when `coupon_count` changes.

Comment: That got it! Thanks for that. I was looking all day for the logic on the mongoid documentation. Couldnt find anything dealing with the AND or OR. Thanks again!

Comment: So I am using this hash and it works in development but in production it will not work. I am using mongodb and trying to check in in console but having trouble. Can you take a look at this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677603/date-works-in-development-but-not-production-rails-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a class method, so `self` in this circumstance references the `Coupon` class rather than a `Coupon` instance.

Try the following:

```
 scope :not_expired, -> { where("expires_at > ? OR expires_at IS NULL", Time.now) }
 scope :previously_used, -> { where("coupon_count > 0 OR coupon_count IS NULL") }

 def self.get(code)
   previously_used.not_expired.find_by!(code: normalize_code(code))
 end
```

Comment: So 2 things... 1. same error only on the expires_at line and 2. I thought you shouldn't hardcode the object into the query like you have at coupon_count > 0

Comment: As long as it's not a dynamic input there's really nothing hardcoded.

Comment: Got the same error ````wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)```` only on the  ````scope :not_expired, -> { where("expires_at > ? OR expires_at IS NULL", Time.now) }````

Comment: Strange, it works for me. It may be related to  mongoid.

Comment: Ok changed scope to ````scope :not_expired, -> { where("expires_at > Time.now OR expires_at IS NULL") }```` and got this error ````SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (16722)```` on the line ````previously_used.not_expired.find_by!(code: normalize_code(code))````

Comment: `.where.not(:expires_at.lt => Time.now)`? I'm not too familiar with mongoid, so I'm not totally sure, but am confident that mongoid is the issue.

Comment: The error you just posted is because `Time.now` is a Ruby expression, not something that would be executable by the DB.

Comment: Your problem is you're using the standard ActiveRecord query DSL but are using Mongoid. The logic above should work, but you'll need to convert your scopes and queries to a syntax supported by mongoid.

Comment: You can't use SQL snippets with Mongoid because MongoDB doesn't understand SQL. Combining OR with scopes in Mongoid is also fraught with problems because there isn't a real query language, just a syntax tree represented by nested hashes.