# Method works in development but not production Rails MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Coupon class and I want my app to check and see how many counts are left on the coupon and if the date for the coupon has expired. I have the following method in my class to check both of these.

```
Coupon class

  def self.get(code)
   where(
    :code => (normalize_code(code)),
    :$and => [
      {
       :$or => [
         { :coupon_count.gte => 1  },
         { :coupon_count    => nil }
       ]
     }, {
       :$or => [
         { :expires_at.gt => Time.now.utc },
         { :expires_at    => nil      }
      ]
     }
    ]
  ).first
 end
```

This works fine in development when I enter a coupon. But in production it does not work. I use my MongoDB shell to create a coupon as follows.

```
db.Coupon.insert({code:'#COUPONNAME',discount_percent: 10, expires_at: new ISODate("2016-05-18"), coupon_count: 10, "description": '1st cold visit sign-up'})
```

It seems that the problem is when the Coupon checks the expires_at date. In development it finds the coupon and works but in production it keeps not finding the coupon. Just for good measure here is my controller method for this.

**EDIT**
I thought the issue was with the date but if I remove the date query it still does not work in production. I am confused why this wont work in production. It is using MongoDB 3.0.10 and mongoid 5.1.0 gem

---

```
charges_controller
  @code = params[:couponCode]

if !@code.blank?
  @coupon = Coupon.get(@code)

  if @coupon.nil?
    flash[:error] = 'Coupon code is not valid or expired.'
    redirect_to new_managers_charge_path(id: @reportapproval.id)
    return
  elsif @coupon.discount_percent == 100
    @reportapproval.report_paid = true
    @reportapproval.free_coupon_used = true
    @reportapproval.save!
    @coupon.coupon_count = @coupon.coupon_count - 1
    @coupon.save!
    redirect_to managers_dashboard_path, :notice => "You have successfully requested a pre-paid report from #{@reportapproval.tenant_last_name} with a 'No-Pay' intro coupon."
    return
  else
    @final_amount = @coupon.apply_discount(@amount.to_i)
    @discount_amount = (@amount.to_i - @final_amount.to_i)
  end
```

Comment: Something is different between your development and production environment, being either the data ( and probably date format ) or the driver version being used. In the latter case it might be about the serialization of the query arguments. Try moving the `:code` condition to be also "within" the `$and` conditions and make sure the result of `normalize_code(code)` is returning what you expect. Not likely related, but you probably really mean `$exists` rather than the `nil` value checks as well. Log the actual queries as issued to the server as well, and spot any differences.

Comment: Wouldn't the collection be `db.coupons`? How are the `code` and `discount_percent` fields being changed? The "returns a coupon" doesn't match the `insert` you did.

Comment: So I get this procedure from the Stripe coupon docs https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/coupons-for-charges the method finds the coupon by the code. The discount_percent does not change. What do you mean db.coupons, when I go to the MongoDB shell I can use something like ````db.Coupon.findOne()```` to find the coupon  but not in my rails app. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @muistooshort WOW! All that and I was calling the wrong model in the MongoDB shell. Thats for pointing out my blatant error. Your the best! Changed the create method to db.coupons and it works perfectly. Funny I used Coupon in the rails irb but had to change in the mongo shell

Comment: Please mark your comment as an answer and I will give you credit

Comment: @NeilLunn: I'm pretty sure he really does want `:expires_at => nil` in the queries rather than `:expires_at.exists => false`, see below. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `Coupon` Mongoid model then the collection in the MongoDB shell would be `db.coupons`. That would explain why:

```
db.Coupon.insert(...)
```

in the MongoDB shell isn't providing what you're expecting to find in your Rails code.

---

As far as Neil's comment about `$exists` versus explicit `nil` checks goes, I think you really do want `nil` (AKA `null` inside MongoDB) checks. Consider this in the MongoDB shell:

```
> db.models.insert({ n: 11 })
> db.models.insert({ n: 0 })
> db.models.insert({ n: null })
> db.models.insert({ })
> db.models.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546e1ce2934dadf379479"), "n" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546e4ce2934dadf37947a"), "n" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546e7ce2934dadf37947b"), "n" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546ecce2934dadf37947c") }
```

So we have a collection with documents that have `n`, don't have `n`, have explicit `null` values for `n`, and non-`null` values for `n`.

Then we can see the difference between Mongoid queries like `:n => nil`:

```
> db.models.find({ n: null })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546e7ce2934dadf37947b"), "n" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546ecce2934dadf37947c") }
```

and `:n.exists => true` (AKA `:n => { :$exists => true }`):

```
> db.models.find({ n: { $exists: true } })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546e1ce2934dadf379479"), "n" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546e4ce2934dadf37947a"), "n" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546e7ce2934dadf37947b"), "n" : null }
```

and `:n => { :$exists => false }`:

```
> db.models.find({ n: { $exists: false } })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571546ecce2934dadf37947c") }
```

So the `:expires_at => nil` queries will find documents which don't have an `expires_at` as well as documents where `expires_at` was explicitly set to `nil`. Both those cases will happen with Mongoid unless you're careful to call `remove_attribute` instead of assigning a `nil` and both cases mean "no expiry date".