# Run a ROR Model method in MongoDB shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, shell

I have a ruby method in my model. I am testing the method in production and want to run the method in the MongoDB shell. What is the syntax to run a ruby method that is in a model. Here is my method.

```
Coupon.rb

 def self.get(code)
  where(
    :code => (normalize_code(code)),
    :$and => [
      {
        :$or => [
          { :coupon_count.gte => 1  },
          { :coupon_count    => nil }
        ]
      }, {
        :$or => [
          { :expires_at.gte => Date.today },
          { :expires_at    => nil }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ).first
end
```

I cannot seem to find a way to run this method in the MongoDB Shell.

Comment: Run `normalize_code` from the Rails console and paste the result into the MongoDB shell. Or implement `normalize_code` in JavaScript so that you can run it from within the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing 2 different things. Your Rails models are written in Ruby language and can be run within Ruby interpreter.

MongoDB shell is basically an interface to your MongoDB instance and it does not have Ruby interpreter. So you **can not call** a Rails model method in MongoDB shell

Comment: Ok thanks. This may explain why I am having problems with my original question. Please take a look at this and let me know if you see what is wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36677603/3877058?sem=2